# Filter by field user role permission

Tags: views, users

I have created *View permission* field in the *events* content type. Its field type is *Role*, so I can select which roles can see the node.

This works fine, but when I add events content type in the view this will displays all the data. I want to filter the data by the *View permission* field for the currently logged-in user.

I want to show data to the roles which I selected in the node *View permission* field. I have tried with contextual filter with user:uid, but I don't get what I am expecting. Actually, I don't know how to do that.

How can I achieve this?

Note: I want to integrate with my content type field *View permission*. I will select a role in View permission field. That roles only can see the view result.

Comment: Are you saying you have tried using contextual filter "Provide default value" >> "User ID from logged in user"? If not please try this.

Comment: I have tried this. Not working.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please don't add _Drupal_ in the title: This Stack Exchange site is about Drupal, so there isn't the need to say it in the title. If it was about WordPress, the question would be off-topic for us.

Comment: Just to make it explicit: Are you using Drupal 8 or Drupal 7?

Comment: `The OP is saying the roles users should have to see the node is in a field of the node itself. That contextual filter would filter the nodes by the author, but it doesn't check the current user has the necessary role. – kiamlaluno♦` I still don't get, but hopefully someone else will.

Comment: I am using drupal7

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the only requirement here is a per-node, role-based, permission setting on content. If that's the case, I'd drop your role reference field in lieu of [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access). The module enables such a requirement and it hooks deeper into the Drupal permission system so you don't have to build a bespoke permission checking for every situation (e.g. views access, node page access, etc.).